# Check multiple variable in if statement in bash script using && operator

Tags: bash

if statement is not working

```
if [ "$diff" -eq 1 ] && [ "$diff1" -eq 1 ] && [ "$diff3" -eq 1 ];

then

$ch=1

fi
```

please anyone help me with this.

error is [: : integer expression expected

Comment: In bash this works:
`if [ "$diff" == 1 ] && [ "$diff1" == 1 ] && [ "$diff3" == 1 ];`

or

`if [ $diff -eq 1 ] && [ $diff1 -eq 1 ] && [ $diff3 -eq 1 ];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
if [[ ("$diff" == 1 && "$diff1" == 1  &&  "$diff3" == 1) ]]; then
    $ch=1
fi
```